# Can't read a cell value from using Jexcel API

Tags: java, jexcelapi

I am trying to read a .xls file by JExecel Api. I can read some column data by using **cell.getContents()** easily. But some column give me mysterious value 1, but column type looks like **Date**. So i check those column type and Find they are Number Type. So i cast those cell in **NumberCell**. But output looks still mysterious 1.

```
Workbook workbook = null;
            try {
                workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook("StandardReport.xls");
                Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
                Cell[] cellRow = sheet.getColumn(0);
                for (int row = 4; row < cellRow.length; row++) {
                    String id = cellRow[row].getContents().trim();
                    if (id.isEmpty() == false) {
                        Cell cell1 = sheet.getCell(1, row);
                        Cell cell2 = sheet.getCell(2, row);
                        Cell cell3 = sheet.getCell(3, row);      

                        System.out.println(cell1.getContents()+"");
                        System.out.println(cell2.getContents()+"");
                        System.out.println(cell3.getContents()+"");

                        if (cell3.getType() == CellType.NUMBER) {                                 
                            NumberCell date=(NumberCell)cell3;                                
                            System.out.println(date.getContents()+"");
                        }


                        /*if (cell3.getType() == CellType.BOOLEAN) {
                            System.out.println("2");
                        }
                        if (cell3.getType() == CellType.BOOLEAN_FORMULA) {
                            System.out.println("3");
                        }
                        if (cell3.getType() == CellType.DATE_FORMULA) {
                            System.out.println("4");
                        }
                        if (cell3.getType() == CellType.EMPTY) {
                            System.out.println("5");
                        }
                        if (cell3.getType() == CellType.ERROR) {
                            System.out.println("6");
                        }
                        if (cell3.getType() == CellType.FORMULA_ERROR) {
                            System.out.println("7");
                        }
                        if (cell3.getType() == CellType.LABEL) {
                            System.out.println("8");
                        }
                        if (cell3.getType() == CellType.NUMBER) {
                            System.out.println("9");
                        }
                        if (cell3.getType() == CellType.NUMBER_FORMULA) {
                            System.out.println("11");
                        }
                        if (cell3.getType() == CellType.STRING_FORMULA) {
                            System.out.println("12");
                        }*/

                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException | BiffException ex) {
               StaticAccess.showMessageDialog("Failed!!", ex);
            }
```

Here is the file link of [StandardReport.xls](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tdpvsopz8atahjk/StandardReport.xls)

Comment: Have you tried to use `date.getValue()` as that is the proper method for an `NumberCell`?

Comment: date.getValue() give me 1.0 ...whats happend i dont know

Comment: Whats the cell value? Not sure if you are supposed to share the excel with possible everyone here

Comment: I already share file link in post. cell value is: 2019-01-01

Comment: Try to cast into `DateCell` and use `getDate()` even if it tells you its a `NumberCell`

Comment: jxl.read.biff.NumberValue cannot be cast to jxl.DateCell ... Please help

Comment: Last suggestion I have is to read as string and parse it afterwards

Comment: System.out.println(cell3.toString()); //give jxl.read.biff.NumberValue@cb548a
and System.out.println(cell3.getContents()); //give 1
Please help me, i will give you Upvote and everything...

Comment: Sorry i found...actually i am selecting wrong sheet..it will be workbook.getSheet(3); thanks for everything...